# Interpreting the reciprocal of the reproductive ratio, $R_0$

Tags: mathematical-modeling, biology, steady-state

$R_0$ is the average number of secondary cases arising from a single infectious individual in a fully susceptible population.

In many of the compartmental models for epidemiology, the parameter $\frac{1}{R_0}$ appears frequently.

In particular, in an SIS model, the non-trivial steady state is $(S^*, I^*) = \left(\frac{1}{R_0}, 1 - \frac{1}{R_0} \right)$.

> Is there any intuitive interpretation one can give to the reproductive ratio's reciprocal?

I'm thinking some sort of average rate of secondary cases, but this doesn't feel right since $S^*$ is a number.